# Magento clear extendware cache programmatically

Tags: magento

I am using 'Extendware Full page cache' magento extension. how to programmatically clear product page cache in extendware.

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically clear product page cache please follow http://vagento.com/magento-automatically-cache-refresh-using-cron/ site article. In this link it'll help you to Cache Refresh programmatically as well as you can set cron to Automatically Cache Refresh Using Cron.

let us know that'll help you or not.